# How to overlay a view above another view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

As suggested by [jjv360](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008736/jjv360) in another question of mine, one way to have a customized paging width for a scrollView is to make scrollView be the size for paging, and then overlaying a transparent UIView over it and doing [overlayView addGestureRecognizer:scrollView.panGestureRecognizer] for the touch event.

This sounds like a great idea and here is my quick question:

Is overlaying just `[view addsubview OLvier]` ? What is the views overlaying method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup... Set the views frame using CGRectMake and overlay using

[scrollview addsubview: view1]

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *yourView = [UIView alloc]init];
yourView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)//whatever values work for you
[self.view addSubview: yourView];
```